# Execution of dynamic mysql query fails

Tags: mysql, bash

In a recent bash script, I required a function to standardize calls to a mysql server. My first version of the function looked like this:

```
mysqlfunc()
{
    args="-A"
    if [ "$1" = "++" ]; then
        shift
        while [ 1 ]; do
            if [ "$1" = "--" ]; then
                shift
                break
            fi
            args="$args $1"
            shift  
        done
    fi

    query="-e \"$*\""
    if [ -f "$1" ]; then
        query="< $1"
    fi

    mysql $args -h<host> -p<password> -P<port> -u<user> <database> $query
}
```

This version of the function produced a syntactically correct mysql statement; executing the evaluated command on the command line worked without error. However, when a file was passed to the function, such as:

```
mysqlfunc $DB_Scripts/mysql_table_create.sql
```

The mysql command would fail, complaining of what appeared to be either incorrect arguments supplied or incorrect syntax. It didn't specify which, only printed the usage help for mysql.

My question: Why does this dynamic statement assignment fail?

---

***Example:***

Function call:

```
mysqlcmd $PATH_TO_FILE/example.sql
```

Mysql command executed:

```
mysql -A -h<host> -p<password> -P<port> -u<user> <database> < <path_to_file>/example.sql
```

Result:

Usage for mysql printed to the terminal

Comment: What is `$args`? Do you really mean to have the first argument to the function be in the `-e` string **and** used as `< $1`? Do you expect any arguments to your function to contain spaces in them? Are you expecting this to be safe for arbitrary input? Add `set -x` to the top of the function and `set +x` to the bottom of it and then run it and see what commands are actually executing.

Comment: @EtanReisner $args contains the options passed in at function invocation (e.g., mysqlfunc --silent "select * from TABLE"). The option parser strips out everything except the sql command to execute, so, yes, it's safe. As I noted already, the command works just fine on the command line.

Comment: `$*` is all the current arguments (including `$1`). Is that what you meant? Are you assigning arguments into `$args` at some point because your snippet doesn't show that. The double quotes in `$query` will not be removed by the shell (so `mysql` will seem them) which may not be what you want. What command **exactly** did it run when it failed and what was the **exact** error message?

Comment: @EtanReisner See my edits. Due to the nature of my work, I cannot provide any more specific details than what I have already.

Comment: Ah. I misread what the if block was doing. Now I see the problem. See http://ideone.com/dgR8KL and see if you can spot it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put shell metacharacters like `<` inside variables and have them function.

That's not how the parser works. The shell doesn't see the `<` in the variable result as a redirection operator it sees it as a literal string.

This is part of what [Bash FAQ 050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) covers.

Comment: Bummer. Guess I was trying to be too creative. My current version of the script doesn't use the query variable, and works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

can you do something like

```
if [ -f "$1" ]; then
  cat $1 | mysql $args -h<host> -p<password> -P<port> -u<user> <database>
else
  mysql $args -h<host> -p<password> -P<port> -u<user> <database> $query
fi
```

works with psql

Comment: That's pretty much what I ended up doing, but explicitly using "< $1", instead of catting the file. Works fine.